# How to greedily add as many equality constraints as possible to a set of inequality constraints?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, graph-algorithm, linear-programming, inequality

I have a set of inequality constraints of the following form:

```
x >= y + 3
y >= z + 4
z >= w + 1
z >= y - 8
w >= x + 0
```

And I guarantee that these constraints have a solution. I also have a set of equality constraints of this form:

```
w = a + 10
a = x + 3
y = z - 7
```

I would like to compute a solution to the inequality constraints that satisfies as many of these equality constraints as possible. A greedy solution is fine, I don't need an optimal solution. I have an algorithm right now, but it is too slow, and would like a more performant solution.

Typical problem sizes are: Number of variables = 1000, Number of inequality constraints = 1000, Number of equality constraints = 200. A solution that runs in < 1 minute is preferable.

Thank you very much!

-Patrick

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/).*

Comment: There is no code. This is an algorithm design question.

Comment: Formulate it as Mixed-integer program (or maybe MISOCP) and look if it works out for you (hard to tell without data). Probably some care has to be taken to keep the formulation convex.